# How to find all pairs of digits that sum to a specific number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a Python function that gets a number as input, and prints all pairs of digits within the number that sums into a per-specified number.

My code is:

```
def f(n,num):
    s = str(n)
    l = []
    for digit in s:
        l.append(digit)
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(len(l)):
            if i != j:
                if (int(l[i]) + int(l[j]) == num):
                    print(l[i]," ",l[j])
```

It works fine, but every pair is printed twice. I couldn't find a way to remove the duplicates and print every pair only once.

Can you assist ? Thank you.

Comment: `for j in range(len(l)):` => `for j in range(i+1,len(l)):` and you can drop the i != j test